# Обрезка видео через ffmpeg на Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i', '/var/****/2333.avi', '-ss', '10', '-t', '500', '-vf', 'cropdetect', '-f', 'null', '-'])
output = p.communicate()
print(output)
```

При выполнении данной команды, на получение координат по которым необходимо будет обрезать видео. Получаю отве

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x29b0480] No such filter: 'cropdetect'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

Как поправить, получить и сразу запомнить данные в переменной. Если не ошибаюсь на bash, получал данный результат

```
crop=$(ffmpeg -i $file -ss 10 -t $(($time_v/2)) -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print  $NF }' | tail -1)
```

Содержимое переменной crop:

```
crop=**,***,***
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265381/ffmpeg-get-value-from-cropdetect

Comment: Но тут для bash, работает. Как тоже самое но на python?

Comment: Вторые сутки просидел в поиске решения, одни ошибки...